# In how many ways can a committee of $6$ people be selected from $7$ men and $6$ women if it can contain at most one of persons A and B?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A committee of $6$ people will be formed with $7$ men and $6$ women.  The oldest of the $7$ men is A and the oldest of the $6$ women is B. It is described that the committee can include at most one of A and B. In how many ways can the committee be chosen?

My attempt:

$13C6- (6C1 \cdot 7C5+6C5 \cdot 7C1) = 1548$

Correct answer is $1386$.

Please help Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how many ways the commitee can be chosen _without_ this constraint?

Comment: I am voting to close since the OP has visited the site since Adolfo posed his query without responding to it.

Comment: No. of ways=No. of ways with only A included + No. of ways with only B included + No. of ways with neither included.

Comment: Thanks  lol hey don't close it I post this before going for dinner =.= wtf, sorry was off to dinner closed the windows righta away,In fact I'm still eating my dinner now   =3= 13C6- (6C1*7C5+6C5*7C1)=1548 Correct answer is 1386

Comment: How do I include only A or B? or neither

Comment: See my answer, you include at most one of A and B by not including both.

Comment: @DreadfulWithMaths  I may have been a bit hasty to close the problem since you are new here.  It is expected that when you pose a question here that you include your attempt to solve the problem (or at least your thoughts on the problem) and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are having.  I have edited your question to include your attempt.

Comment: Thanks for all the edits and clarifications sweetie!I'm sorry >< I thought it would be a while before answers come so I went to ate dinner xD hahaha >_< didn't know I need to provide my workings. will take note in the future! Thanks a lot :)!

Answer (score 2):

From all 13C6 solutions, you must subtract the solutions where both A and B are chosen.

If you choose both A and B, there are 11C4 possibilities for the other 4 in the committee.

So 13C6 - 11C4 = 1386.

You calculated the committees where it was not allowed to have exactly one of A and B.

Comment: @@ thanks a lot, i feel so dumby for not being able to think of this

Answer (score 0):

Pieter21 has provided you with a valid and efficient solution.

Your attempt was incorrect since you subtracted the sum of the number of ways of selecting five men and one woman and the number of ways of selecting five women and one man. However, it is possible to select a committee of six people containing at most one of A and B that contains more than one person of each sex.

Here is an alternate solution:

A committee that contains at most one of A and B either contains neither A nor B or it contains exactly one of them.

If the committee of six people contains neither A nor B, we must select six of the other eleven available people, which can be done in $$\binom{11}{6}$$ ways.

If the committee contains exactly one of A and B, we must select one of A and B, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways, and select five of the other eleven people, which can be done in $\binom{11}{5}$ ways.  Hence, the number of committees of six people that contain exactly one of A and B is 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{11}{5}$$

Therefore, the number of committees that can be formed with at most one of A and B is 
$$\binom{11}{6} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{11}{5}$$

Comment: Thanks! :) Helpful in helping me understand!